# How can I patch this Ruby module to avoid code duplication?

Tags: ruby

I would like to modify a module that I'm using in Rails. At the moment, I am including the module and then also patching some of its functionality:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  include Discard::Model
  self.discard_column = :deleted_at

  # patching the module's .discard method to allow for discarded_at to be a variable
  def discard(discarded_at = DateTime.now)
    return false if discarded?
    run_callbacks(:discard) do
      update_attribute(self.class.discard_column, discarded_at)
    end
  end
end
```

For reference, [the original `.discard` method can be seen here](https://github.com/jhawthorn/discard/blob/f391785f5d9898d6ce67cee0b9929051e1b5bb44/lib/discard/model.rb#L118).

### How can I abstract this patch into a reusable super-module?

To save repeating this code, I would like to be able to pull my patch out into a new version of the original module and use that instead of the original.

What I would like:

```
# task.rb
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  include SuperDiscard
end
```

```
# super_discard.rb
module SuperDiscard 
  extend Discard::Model

  # NB While this hints at what I want it definitely doesn't work :(
  include Discard::Model
   def discard(discarded_at = DateTime.now)
    return false if discarded?
    run_callbacks(:discard) do
      update_attribute(self.class.discard_column, discarded_at)
    end
  end

  included do 
    self.discard_column = :deleted_at
  end
end
```

I was hoping that the above would work but it consistently fails. I really struggle to wrap my head around what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can `include Discard::Model` in the `included` block

```rb
# super_discard.rb
module SuperDiscard
 extend ActiveSupport::Concern

 included do
  include Discard::Model
  self.discard_column = :deleted_at
  def discard(discarded_at = DateTime.now)
    return false if discarded?
    run_callbacks(:discard) do
      update_attribute(self.class.discard_column, discarded_at)
    end
  end
 end
end

# task.rb
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  include SuperDiscard
end
```